# Multiple unique instances of the same virtual product

Tags: wordpress, download, woocommerce, e-commerce

I need to associate multiple unique .zip files to a single product, unique as in it can only be purchased once.

1 product => 50 unique .zip files, every time a user purchases an instance of this product, the download file generated is a unique one.

Purchase 1 => .zip 1,

Purchase 2 => .zip 2

etc

Comment: Can you post any code or what so ever?

Comment: Sorry, it's just generic Wordpress site with WooCommerce installed. I didn't manage to find any plugin that handles this.